# Building a deck: can you shift the load points?

Tags: deck, design, load

The reasons for the below design are:
-I want to place the stairs adjacent to the wall
-I want to use the deck posts as rail posts as well
-this is replacing an old deck and I do not want to dig new holes
At the bottom I have 4 beams 2x8  (a pair on each side sitting on the deck supports)
Just below the deck I have two 2x8 beams parallel to the house, one of them sitting under the joists, the other sitting at the same level with the joists

I need to understand if this is an acceptable design (all the beams will follow the recommended cantilever lengths) I just ned to know if there could be other potential issues

[image]

Comment: You can, but your low beams need to be adequate to carry the entire deck, and you probably can't cantilever them that far. You'll also have a messy appearance unless you skirt it. I'd move the holes.

Comment: I will skirt the bottom side. The very reason why the upper front beam is not a at the same level with the back side beam is because I need clearance from the front side to access the storage under the deck

Comment: The bigger issue may be lateral stability. How will you keep the thing from swaying on the unbraced posts? You might have to let in diagonals somewhere. The added cost and complexity here aren't worth saving a hole or two. Hire some temp help.

Comment: the posts will be notched and slided in between the two bottom beams like here https://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/FH02MAY_UT_MAKPOS_05.JPG  There will also be lateral braces

Comment: You don't have any dimensions. What is the length of the cantilever on the left end?

Comment: Securing the post to the beam won't be adequate. At best it'll allow enough sway to make your deck's occupants seasick. At worst, the high torque will tear the beam loose.

Comment: @ArchonOSX  left post to the deck support is 13"  right side post (closer to the house) to the deck support that is next to the house I have 21"

Comment: Your drawing looks the other way around but without dimensions or scale it is hard to see. Anyway, your vertical posts need to be on top of the lower beams. And I would add a couple vertical supports in the middle of the span to transfer the load and support the cantilever. After that, I wouldn't worry about cantilevering less than 2 feet. Now, 3 or 4 feet would be a different story.

Comment: yes the figure is not to scale, that is true